# eliminar select options de outros selects

Tags: jquery, html

Boas, eu tenho 4 selects html e em todos eles tenho as mesmas opções, eu queria que quando fosse selecionada uma opção do primeiro select essa mesma opção fosse colocada como disabled nos outros selects é possível fazer isso de forma eficiente e rápida com jquery?

Comment: Mas só o primeiro `<select>` é que desativa opções nos outros, o inverso não acontece ?

Comment: sim o inverso também acontece, agradeço pela chamada de atenção

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opção mais simples é capturar o evento 'change' do select, fazer um ciclo for a partir dai o ***siblings*** ajuda:

### HTML

```
<select name="select1">
    <option>default</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>

<select name="select2">
    <option>default</option>
    <option value="1">Test</option>
    <option value="2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="3">Test 3</option>
</select>
```

### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('select').change(function() {

        var value = $(this).val();

        $(this).siblings('select').children('option').each(function() {
            if ( $(this).val() === value ) {
                $(this).attr('disabled', true).siblings().removeAttr('disabled');   
            }
        });

    });

});
```

> Dado um objeto jQuery que representa um conjunto de elementos DOM, o
>   **[.siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)** método nos permite pesquisar através dos irmãos desses
>   elementos na árvore DOM e construir um novo objeto jQuery a partir dos
>   elementos correspondentes. *[Ver mais](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)*

[**Exemplo a funcionar.**](https://jsfiddle.net/1kc3kse3/)

Answer (score 1):

Coloco todas as tags select em um array para iterar depois

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
```

Digo que quando o select mudar o valor, chamar a função a seguir

```
selects[i].onchange = function(e) {
```

Salvo o valor atual do select separadamente apenas para clareza, pois não precisava, uma vez que o resto está no mesmo escopo
var val = this.value;

Agora eu procuro em todos os selects se algum já possui o mesmo valor que foi selecionado agora

```
for (var z = 0; z < selects.length; z++) {
```

Aqui eu preciso da posição do select atual, pois você precisa que a verificação ocorra nos outros

```
var index = Array.prototype.indexOf.call(selects, this);
```

Aqui eu verfico se não é o select atual e se o valor selecionado é igual ao do atual

```
if ((z !== index) && selects[z].value === val) {
```

Agora eu vou desselecionar a tag option selecionada

```
for (var o = 0; o < options.length; o++) {
    if (options[o].selected) {
        options[o].selected = false;
    }
```

Aqui eu seleciono novamente a primeira padrão
(Qual a sua opção de férias?)

```
options[0].selected = true;
```

Comment: de onde provem este `i` ? `selects[i].onchange`